# Installing enum package causes pip to not work

Tags: python-2.7, pip, package

I installed a fresh version of `pytodos` package using `pip` (`pip install pytodos`). It requires `enum` package to be installed, so it was installed automatically. After this had happened every attempt to do anything with `pip`, that is to install or uninstall any package, resulted in this error:

```
_ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

But when I removed every file that starts with "enum" from `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
cd ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
rm -rf enum*
```

..., I was able to install and uninstall packages once again. After installing `enum` package again (`pip install enum`), everything repeats.

What could be the cause of such behavior?

Comment: is that python 2?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, yes this is python2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4020 you need to uninstall `enum` and install `enum34` or similar instead. Try:

```
pip install --upgrade enum34
```

Comment: As I just said, after installing `enum`, I can't install, **nor uninstall** anything, including `enum`. Only deleting by hand helps. And unfortunately `pytodos` requires `enum`. So, it gets installed whenever I try to install `pytodos`.

Comment: What if you remove both, then install `enum34`, then try to install `pytodos`?  Does that still automatically install `enum`?  If so, this whole thing is a packaging error and you'll need to build `pytodos` yourself.

Comment: After deleting `enum` (`rm -rf enum*`), uninstalling it (`pip uninstall enum`) gives this message `Skipping enum as it is not installed.`. And attempts to uninstall `enum34` result in appearance of this message: `Cannot uninstall 'enum34'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`. But when I run `pip install --upgrade enum34`, and then install `pytodos` it still required `enum` and installed it, but further use of pip did not result in any error anymore.

Comment: I used `pip install cryptography==2.9`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solution is, drop your pip folder, then again reinstall pip
and other essential dependencies.