# Can not run pyinstaller, as I get enum34 error

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I finished a python app, and now I want to packing into an executable, for an end user.
I use windows 7 64 bit, and my python version it's **Python 3.7.2**

I already tried several solution and none worked for me, as follow:

1. I tried to run pyinstaller inside an virtual environment, after installed all required packages:
   [image: virtual environment]

So I can't say it's because of my machine.

2. As far I know I don't use *enum* or *enum34* in my application. Maybe one of this dependency packages does:

```
    beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
    bs4==0.0.1
    certifi==2021.10.8
    charset-normalizer==2.0.12
    et-xmlfile==1.1.0
    idna==3.3
    openpyxl==3.0.9
    Pillow==9.1.0
    requests==2.27.1
    soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
    urllib3==1.26.9
```

3. I already tried the most logical solution:
   [image: pip uninstall enum34]

which is kinda annoying... I have it installed, but I don't have it installed.

4. I already tried the solution to [uninstall both enum34 and enum, and then reinstall enum34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747079/installing-enum-package-causes-pip-to-not-work#answer-51747115):

```
    >pip uninstall enum34
    >pip uninstall enum
    >pip install --upgrade enum34
```

5. I have tried both sugettion to [upgade smartsheet-SDK and upgrade it by git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465081/i-cant-package-my-program-with-pyinstaller-because-i-have-enum34-installed-can#answer-54466345):

```
    >pip install smartsheet-python-sdk --upgrade
```

and

```
    >git clone -b tw-updates-2.0 https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk.git
    >cd smartsheet-python-sdk
    >python setup.py install
```

6. I tried also to [uninstall cryptography package first, and then uninstall enum and enum34](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4020#issuecomment-459159656):

Any ideas ?
On python 3.8 have tried anyone ?

**UPDATE 1**

So after I gave up **pyinstaller**, I tried [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) to see that I get the same error of *enum34* there also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the issue, by:

1. uninstall python (I used *3.7.13*)
2. manually delete all folders from the main python installation folder
3. reinstall python (*[3.7.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)*)

Now it works both **pyautoinstaller** and **auto-py-to-exe**, despite the fact that in the [documentation of pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/requirements.html) it says:

> PyInstaller runs in Windows 8 and newer. It can create graphical
> windowed apps (apps that do not need a command window).